# WP7 - Monitor outgoing Messages

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I'm trying to create an application that keeps a count on the number of text messages a user has sent from his/her Windows Phone 7 device.

I'm assuming that to do this, I need to have an app running in the background, which I now believe is possible with the SDK v7.1.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get my app to react to an outgoing message. I.e. how do I increment a counter when a message is sent? Is there a particular event that's triggered that I can set up a handler for?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to be notified that an outgoing text message has been sent - Windows Phone is much more locked down than (say) Android.

Comment: Dang. Can you think of any other ways to achieve what I'm trying then? I don't see how it would be possible without having an event for outgoing messages.